# How do I go about proving da db/a^(-2) is a left Haar measure on the affine group?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $ G $ be the affine group, in other words $ G := \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\} $ with binary operation defined by $ (b,a)\cdot(x,s) = (ax+b,as) $. Now, $ G $ is a locally compact group and thus has a left (resp. right) Haar measure. In particular I know that $ d\mu = a^{-2}da\,db $ defines a left Haar measure on $ G $. How do I go about proving that this is true? -that this is in fact a left Haar measure on $ G $?

Comment: Hint: What is the Jacobian of left multiplication by $(b,a)$?

Comment: Maybe I'm over complicating things... so $ \int_G f((b,a)\cdot(x,s))dx\,ds = \int_G f(ax+b,as)dx\,ds $, substituting $ \beta = ax+b $ and $ \alpha = as $ yields $ d\beta = a\,dx $ and $ d\alpha = a\,ds $ thus $ a^2dx\,ds = d\beta\,d\alpha $. Something along these lines?

Comment: Hmm.. I can't get this to work, for $ \int_G f((b,a)\cdot(x,s))ds\,dx $ and substitution (as above) $ \beta = ax+b, \alpha = as $ I get the Jacobian $ J(\beta,\alpha) = a^{-2} $ , but $ a $ was a constant here and I suppose I would like something which would imply a $ s^{-2} $ somewhere...?

Comment: Overcomplicating, or not complicating it enough … see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems reasonable to guess that the Haar measure is absolutely continuous wrt two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, so let us try with $\lambda(x,s)\,dx\,ds$ as the left Haar measure. This means that we want
$$\int_G f(ax+b,as)\lambda(x,s)\,dx\,ds=\int_G f(x,s)\lambda(x,s)\,dx\,ds$$
for all $(a,b)\in G$ and all integrable functions $f$. After substituting $u=ax+b$ and $v=as$ in the integral on the left, then renaming $u$ and $v$ to $x$ and $s$, that becomes
$$\int_G f(x,s)\lambda\bigl((x-b)/a,s/a\bigr)a^{-2}\,dx\,ds=\int_G f(x,s)\lambda(x,s)\,dx\,ds,$$
so we just need to have
$$\lambda\bigl((x-b)/a,s/a\bigr)a^{-2}=\lambda(x,s).$$
Since $b$ can be anything, we conclude that $\lambda(x,s)$ cannot depend on $x$, so let us just write it $\lambda(s)$ instead
$$\lambda(s/a)a^{-2}=\lambda(s).$$
Recalling that this is to to be true for all $a,s\ne0$, we put $a=s$, and get
$$\lambda(s)=\lambda(1)a^{-2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful, though I realize now that what I was looking for was probably just something along these lines:
$$ \int_G f(ax+b,as)s^{-1}dx\,ds = \int_G f(u,v)\left(\frac{v}{a}\right)^{-2}a^{-2}\,du\,dv = \int_G f(u,v)v^{-2}du\,dv. $$
I just wanted to see that it was in fact translation invariant.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, I thought of doing just that, but this way you have a way to identify the Haar measure on other groups as well.

Comment: I have used this kind of arguments many times but I always fail finding some argument to assure, (beside intuition) that the resulting invariant measure is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure anyone has a good reason?

Comment: @Maximiliano I haven't got any brilliant insights, but at least it should be clear that Haar measure is nonatomic: For if it has a point mass at one point, it must have one at every point, which is absurd. Also, for a compact Lie group, you can always average all translates of Lebesgue measure wrt Haar measure (i.e., perform a convolution), to get another Haar measure, this time a.c. wrt. Lebesgue measure. By uniqueness of Haar measure, this must be the original measure (up to a constant multiplier).

Comment: But ultimately, the proof is in the pudding: You guess it's absolutely continuous, you find out what is required of the Radon–Nikodym derivative, you find a function satisfying the requirements, and conclude (if your argument works in reverse, as it should) that the resulting measure is invariant.